# Restart App after every Test Case

Tags: android, testing, android-activity, robotium

I'm using Robotium and ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 and I need to restart my app completely after every test case. The app does not find the view ids in all test cases following the first one.

That means my view is null in TestCase2 and that doesn't make sense.

*The app has a loading screen. This loading screen only appears before testCase1, and solo.getCurrentActivity() returns different Activity instances.*

```
public void testCase1() throws Exception {

    solo.getCurrentActivity(); //returns LoadingActivity
    solo.sleep(5000);
    solo.getCurrentActivity(); //returns MainActivity

    View view = (TextView) solo.findViewById("Button1", TIMEOUT_VIEW_SEARCH);
    solo.clickOnView(view);
}

public void testCase2() throws Exception {

    solo.getCurrentActivity(); //returns LoadingActivity
    solo.sleep(5000);
    solo.getCurrentActivity(); //returns LoadingActivity

    View view = (TextView) solo.findViewById("Button1", TIMEOUT_VIEW_SEARCH);
    solo.clickOnView(view);
}
```

The method findviewById(...) searches for the Id of the view based on current activity. This works fine.

setUp and tearDown look like the two below. I'm on the start screen when testCase2 starts, but the app didn't start completely new.

```
@Override
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    solo = new MySolo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
}

@Override
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    solo.finishOpenedActivities();
    super.tearDown();
}
```

**EDIT:** I've edited the question. Both methods are in different Activities.

Comment: How does your testcase1 even find the view? you're supposed to give an integer id, not a string name into findViewById()...

Comment: Hi. In MySolo:         this.getCurrentActivity().getResources().getIdentifier("Button1", "id", this.getCurrentActivity().getPackageName()));

Comment: I've edited my question. Seems like both methods are in different activities...

Answer (score 0):

Use solo.getView() instead of findViewById.